# arcsin wrong values?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i am trying to calculate an angle of a body in my game.

i have this :

```
power= sqrt (   pow( ( Xs-x),2)+pow((Ys-y),2)  );
    angle=( asin( (Ys-y ) / power )  )-90;
    cannonBody->SetTransform(cannonBody->GetPosition(), (-angle ) );
    NSLog(@"%f",(  x));
    NSLog(@"%f",( y));
    NSLog(@"%f",( Xs-x));   
    NSLog(@"%f",(Ys-y));    
    NSLog(@"%f",power);
    NSLog(@"%f", CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES( -angle));
```

somehow i get `POWER`  and `(Ys-y)`  good values( 68/82 which is 0.82=56 degrees)
        and the log always shows angle values of -5100 , even if i convert from radians..
whats wrong here ?

thanks.

Comment: Can you post the exact number you put in `asin` and the exact number it outputs?

Comment: WAG: Are all the variables you're printing actually `floats`, or are you doing some kind of data conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
angle=( asin( (Ys-y ) / power )  )-90;
```

This looks deeply suspicious. The `asin` function returns an angle in radians -- subtracting `90` from that is about guaranteed not to make any sense.

By the way, `atan2()` is easier and much more stable for finding the direction of a 2D vector. Using an arcsine risks large rounding errors when the angle is close to right. (Most math libraries actually compute arcsines by doing the *inverse* of your calculation and applying a hardware atan2 instructions).

Comment: This is definitely the answer. 90 radians is ~5157 degrees, so `56-5157=-5100` is right.